# Getting `Cannot GET /todos`

Tags: express, post, get

I've created a simple Express app and am trying to use Postman to test my POST route. I continually get the `Cannot GET /todos` error. Any suggestions on the below code?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const pool = require('./db');


//middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

//routes
app.post("/todos", async (req, res) => {
   try {
        console.log(req.body);
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
   }
});

app.listen(3050, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port 3050`);
})
```

Comment: Verify that you're using the `POST` HTTP method for your request with Postman

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to make a `GET` request to a `POST` route. You will need to change the HTTP verb to `POST` by clicking the dropdown to the left of the request URL.

[image]